# How do I format this CASE expression inside a WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to set the WHERE clause to query ALL urgency levels (1,2,3,4)
when "All" is selected.

The values for @Priority is:
1 - (Critical)
2 - (High)
3 - (Medium)
4 - (Low)
All - (All Priorities)

....

```
WHERE Facility = 'HQ'
 AND Urgency = CASE WHEN @Priority = 'All' THEN IN ('1','2','3','4')
    ELSE Urgency = @Priority
END
```

=================

So, if '1' is selected as @Priority, then Urgency = 1, if '2' is selected, then Urgency = 2.   If 'All' is selected, THEN "Urgency IN ('1','2','3','4')".

Is there a way to do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 WHERE 
    Facility = 'HQ' AND
    Urgency = CASE WHEN @Priority = 'All' THEN Urgency
                   ELSE @Priority END
```

Comment: Wow..simple.   Thanks mxix!